# Could not resolve view with name 'HelloWorld' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vue.js

I started study Spring Boot just.

I want to display html page.

But It doesn't work.

If I change `HelloWorld.html` to `HelloWorld.ftl` I can display ftl page, but the `vue.js` is not resolve file.

Below is my Spring boot configuration File and Controller.

Application:

```
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/**
```

Resources: `static/js/vue.js`, `tempates/HelloWorld.html`

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "HelloWorld";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring boot provides plug and play type facilities that is the beauty of spring boot. Same thing is applicable here for serve static content from locations in web application with spring boot. By default spring boot serves static resources from classpath as default property:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/
```

And default static path pattern is:

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/**
```

But it is good practice to provide other than default.

However spring boot also provides customization of that configuration programmatically as well by implementing `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AddCustomLocations {
    @Bean
    WebMvcConfigurer configurer () {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").
                          addResourceLocations("classpath:/my-custom-location/");
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        SpringApplication app =
                  new SpringApplication(AddCustomLocations.class);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

Now add new static content like `src/main/resources/new-custom-location/page1.js` and when url pattern like `http://localhost:8080/pages/page1.js` found then page1.js will served as static resource.

Now for `templates/HelloWorld.html`, default properties modification is required (assumes folder `templates` is already there):

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

Corresponding html pages under directory `/templates/` will be rendered by viewResolver.

## Edited Answer:

If you are using `@EnableWebMvc` then just remove it. Your problem should be resolved.
If still problem is not resolved then override `addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry)` method of class `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` as we have done in earlier code. Add below code snippet on the above code  after  `addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)` method.

```
@Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/test").setViewName("testPage");
    }
```

prefix `/templates/` and Suffix `.html` will be added by view resolver.

Comment: Use this ,I can resolve my js and css and images ,but when I use html in springboot and appliction as you . I can not visit index.html. show javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet . but when I change .html to ftl . all is ok . please tell why if you know. Thanks

Comment: @Ezreal, I think FreeMarker is configured on your class path , so just remove the dependency from class path if exist. Now second thing is you have not provided your actual code for index.html by which we can provide any update, even though i am providing solution as per my understanding.Please refer my edited answer.